# How to get UIImage From UIImageView While tapping on UIImageView with UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have added `UITapGestureRecognizer` to `UIImageView`, which is in `UITableViewCell`, `UITapGestureRecognizer` handler is in `UITableViewCell`'s FileOwner.

When I tap on the `UIImageView` the handler method is being called and its parameter also has `UIImageView` but when I check `imageview.image`, I find that `imageview` doesn't have any image: where it has gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks hp...I was doing the same but it didn't worked for me...Now I am doing this by Using `UIButton`instead of `UIImageView`. I attached the handler with button, set the `button.backgroundImage` and then got the image anywhere, I wanted... Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used in my project & it worked fine.

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];


    //Do stuff here...
    // I assume that your imgview is imgView11

    if (imgView11.frame.origin.x < location.x && location.x < something
        && imgView11.frame.origin.y < location.y && location.y < something) {

        largeImgView.image = imgView11.image;
    }
}
```

If you could share your piece of code then I will edit my answer to solve your problem